# Oracle SQL: join a table of dates with different IDs

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here is a sample of my data:

```
DATES          ACCT_ID           AMT
31-JAN-13   0000000117  137.6
31-MAY-13   0000000117  245.96
30-JUN-13   0000000117  8162.97
31-JUL-13   0000000117  158.85
31-OCT-13   0000000117  55.44
30-NOV-13   0000000117  0
31-JAN-14   0000000117  485.78
28-FEB-14   0000000117  588.28
31-MAR-14   0000000117  2315.56
31-JAN-13   0000000133  8291.45
30-APR-13   0000000133  21241.54
31-JUL-13   0000000133  22185.75
31-AUG-13   0000000133  19770.89
30-NOV-13   0000000133  15168.48
31-DEC-13   0000000133  11376.65
28-FEB-14   0000000133  11910.58
31-MAR-14   0000000133  8893.84
30-APR-14   0000000133  12093.9
```

What I want to do is to join this table with a table of all month end dates in the 2-year horizon. ie:

```
DATES
31-JAN-13
28-FEB-13
31-MAR-13
30-APR-13
31-MAY-13
30-JUN-13
31-JUL-13
31-AUG-13
30-SEP-13
31-OCT-13
30-NOV-13
31-DEC-13
31-JAN-14
31-JAN-14
28-FEB-14
31-MAR-14
30-APR-14
```

For each date that a value is not available from the original table, I want to show it in the result, copy the ACCT_ID, and let AMT be `null`.

For example, I want:

```
31-JAN-13   0000000117  137.6
28-FEB-13   0000000117  null
31-MAR-13   0000000117  null
30-APR-13   0000000117  null
31-MAY-13   0000000117  245.96
......
```

A simplified version of my current code is:

```
select * from table_amt
right join table_dates
using (acct_id)
order by (dates)
```

However, a simple right join does not work, since I am performing `join` accross different accounts. For example, notice that there is a record on 31-MAY-13 for account 0000000117 but not for 0000000133, in my result a null observation for date 31-MAY-13 and account 0000000133 is not added as I want it to.

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the query you're using then? It's difficult to fix a problem with your code without the actual code... an outer join should be sufficient to get the result set you describe. It'd be useful to have a representation of the result set you'd like as well.

Comment: Copy what acct id? if it isn't in the original table then there is no acct ID right?

Comment: Is the `ACCT_ID` in the other table?  If so, why wouldn't adding the `ACCT_ID` to the `On` clause work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are at least on 10g, you can use a Partition Outer Join :

```
select dt.dates, d.acct_id, d.amt
from table_dates dt
    left outer join table_amt d partition by (acct_id)
        on d.dates = dt.dates
order by d.acct_id, to_date(dt.dates);
```

For more on this method, read: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25555/tdpdw_sql.htm#TDPDW00721

Answer (score 0):

Gather up all of the unique accounts, join them to the end dates to get all of your unique rows, then gather up the amount:

```
select m.date,
       a.acct_id,
       (select sum(table_amt.amt)
          from table_amt
         where table_amt.date = m.date
           and table_amt.acct_id = a.acct_id) as amt
from   table_dates m,
       (select distinct acct_id from table_amt) a
```

This query isn't efficient but if the table sizes are small then hopefully it runs fast enough for your needs.